# Case reading input parameters being specific letters or any number

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to convert a bunch of if/elses in case statement, but I'm having problem to set this rules:

```
./overload.sh k --> input valid (already done)
./overload.sh c --> input valid (already done)
./overload.sh (any range of number) --> input valid (dont know how to do)
./overload.sh (exception) --> input invalid and error message (already done)
```

I don't know how to make case understand that is to accept any number as a valid option or k or c, and any other input is an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on extended patterns, you can match a number as a string consisting solely of digits:

```
shopt -s extglob
case "$1" in
    k) echo "Got k" ;;
    c) echo "Got c" ;;
    +([[:digit:]]) ) echo "Got a number" ;;
    *) echo "Invalid input: $1" ;;
esac
```

`+(...)` matches one or more of whatever pattern is inside; it is equivalent to the regular expression `(...)+`. Here, `...` is the character class `[:digit:]`, which matches whatever characters are considered digits in your current locale (typically, `[0-9]`).

Comment: Perfect chepner, even if I didnt put any parameter it worked well to exception, thank you!